# Sort treemap on value

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I have a `treemap<Integer,Float>`. How can I sort the the map on float point number?

Is there any quick way? or I have to write the comparator for the map?

Comment: @OP: Take note of the caveats on the accepted answer of the duplicate question.  There are a _lot_ of ways in which that solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, you can't (correctly, reliably) sort a `Map` implementation by the values.  (The implementations you might see claiming otherwise are hackish, unreliable, and behave *really weirdly* -- rejecting duplicate values, throwing exceptions on attempts to look at keys not in the map, getting unrecoverably corrupted if the backing map changes...)

Instead, sort the list of entries explicitly:

```
List<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Float>>() {
  public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e1, Map.Entry<Integer, Float> e2){
    return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
  }
});
```

If you liked, you could then put this into a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Float> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Float>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Float> entry : list) {
  sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I depends on what the OP is asking - the original map remains unsorted (wrt the values).

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no reliable implementation which would do so.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution might be to use LinkedHashMap instead, and sort it by values. See this:
[How to sort a LinkedHashMap by its value class's field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117553/how-to-sort-a-linkedhashmap-by-its-value-classs-field)